# How to use wildcard in transform message mule 3?

Tags: mule

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
(payload.data filter ((item, index) -> item.username == flowVars.fname))[0].id
```

How to use wildcard in this expression so that item.username matched with flowVars.fname with case insensitive?

Comment: Do you want the *contents* of item.username to be compared case insensitively?

Comment: Yes. I want to compare it insensitively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the comparison is case insensitive just convert the values to uppercase before comparing.

Example:

```
((upper item.username) == (upper flowVars.fname))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But this workssss! Thanksss